# Behavior of canceling a dialog

Tags: wpf, user-interface

Let's say you have a basic CRM system, with customers and addresses. Each customer can have many addresses in the system.

Now let's say you open up an window to edit an existing customer. In the window, there is a list of addresses. You double click an address, and a window opens up to edit the address.

Now, let's say the user edits the address and hits "OK" to save his changes. Then he decides he wants to cancel his changes to the customer, so he hits "Cancel" on the main window.

Does the change he made to the customer's address still go through? Or is this rolled back. What is the standard behavior here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMO, pressing "Cancel" on the main window should cancel all changes made to that customer, including those in a sub-window. If the UI were changed so that the customer's address were edited in the main window directly, then in that the case the changes definitely wouldn't be saved. I don't think the sub-window case is any different.

Comment: Ok, this is what I was thinking, but wanted to get opinions of others. Thanks!